# Create table as select using dblink doesn't move all the rows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We are moving from an amazon ec2 database to an amazon rds database.  Most of the tables are small and could be moved using sql developer copy commands but a couple are bigger (3M+ records).  In order to speed those up, I created database links between the two system.  Those work fine.  I then ran the following:

```
create table schema.tablename as select * from schema.tablename@ec2db;
```

ec2db is the old database.  The table there contains 3,503,064 records.  However the NEW databse table only contains 3,454,685 records.  No errors were generated during the create table statement.  This is repeatable (ie: I drop the table and run it again, and it loads the same number of records.)

Any ideas why this would happen?  Why would the contents of a table when I do a select (*) not be the same as the contents of the same table (fully specified) when I do a create table?

Comment: How are you determining the number of rows in the table?  Are you sure that you don't have any uncommitted transactions in the session where you are doing the `count(*)`?  Are you doing the `count(*)` over the database link?  Or directly on the source database?

Comment: I'm doing the count(*) directly on each database.  Didn't try it over the dblink.

Comment: Also, in order to get everything either committed or rolled back I had the old database bounced.